# Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude Setting

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am using VS 2017 to debug a running process.

First, I generated PDB with DotPeek.
[image]

Second, I pointed the directory of pdb location ("C:\PdbDestination") in VS 2107.
[image]

Third, I attached to a process which uses that particular assembly, modules are loaded, however, symbol loading is disabled.
[image]
The expected result is for the Symbol Status to show "Symbol Loaded".

Could someone please let me know anything I could have possibly missed?

**I was able to fix the issue** by manually loading it from Modules tab, but I would still like to know what is the actual root cause (e.g. Include/Exclude setting?) that disables the symbols loading.

Comment: How about running your VS as the admin? Generally it will require the enough access permission to load certain files.

Comment: Hi @JackZhai-MSFT , Yes I did use admin right for debugging

Comment: I have just updated the question above that I actually managed to load the symbol if I did it manually and successfuly entered the breakpoint.

Comment: Please use the default cache symbols directory in your side, view the result. As far as I know, it was in the Temp\SymbolCache folder. You could reset your VS settings, and then enable the Microsfot Symbol Servers, click OK, it would use that directory automatically. In addition, please disable debugging option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging. Debug your app again.

Comment: What about this issue in your side? Any update, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 17):

Please check if "Load all modules, unless excluded" is selected.

Go to Options -> Debugging -> Symbols
[image: Visual Studio: Debugs -> Options dialog]

Comment: Not sure to understand. Should we select it or not?

Comment: @DRz You should select but it requires pretty long time to loading required library.. I wonder theres another options.